# DB2 SQL filter query result by evaluating an ID which has two types of entries

Tags: sql, if-statement, db2, case

After many attempts I have failed at this and hoping someone can help. The query returns every entry a user makes when items are made in the factory against and order number. For example

```
Order Number   Entry type  Quantity
3000          1           1000
3000          1           500
3000          2           300
3000          2           100
4000          2           1000
5000          1           1000
```

What I want to the query do is to return filter the results like this

If the order number has an entry **type 1 and 2** return the row which is type 1 only 
otherwise just return row whatever the type is for that order number.

So the above would end up:

```
Order Number   Entry type  Quantity
3000          1           1000
3000          1           500
4000          2           1000
5000          1           1000
```

Currently my query (DB2, in very basic terms looks like this ) and was correct until a change request came through!

Select * from bookings where type=1 or type=2

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from bookings
    left outer join (
       select order_number,
          max(case when type=1 then 1 else 0 end) + 
             max(case when type=2 then 1 else 0 end) as type_1_and_2
          from bookings
          group by order_number
    ) has_1_and_2 on 
       type_1_and_2 = 2
       has_1_and_2.order_number = bookings.order_number
    where 
        bookings.type = 1 or 
        has_1_and_2.order_number is null
```

Find all the orders that have both type 1 and type 2, and then join it.

If the row matched the join, only return it if it is type 1
If the row did not match the join (`has_type_2.order_number is null`) return it no matter what the type is.

Answer (score 0):

A ["common table expression"](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzintsel.htm) [CTE] can often simplify your logic.  You can think of it as a way to break a complex problem into conceptual steps.  In the example below, you can think of g as the name of the result set of the CTE, which will then be joined to

```
    WITH g as
    ( SELECT order_number, min(type) as low_type
        FROM bookings
        GROUP BY order_number
    )
    SELECT b.*
      FROM g 
      JOIN bookings b   ON  g.order_number = b.order_number
                        AND g.low_type     = b.type
```

The JOIN ON conditions will work so that if both types are present then low_type will be 1, and only that type of record will be chosen.  If there is only one type it will be identical to low_type.

This should work fine as long as 1 and 2 are the only types allowed in the bookings table.  If not then you can simply add a WHERE clause in the CTE and in the outer SELECT.

Comment: Good grief.  It appears I had answered the question backwards.  My apologies.  The edit above should give you what you asked for.